# SSL Certificate pinning in Android app that uses maps, play services, analytics etc

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate

[Corresponding issue on github issue tracker](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1846)

I have been doing a fair bit of reading about preventing man in the middle attacks on my app using tools like Charles, Fiddler, mitm etc. I liked the idea of pinning my server's SSL certificate since that means all other certs will throw an error which is what I want.

But, the app uses libs like google maps, play services, analytics tools etc which must be using their own SSL certs. Does it mean that I would need to manually pin the certs of all these libs too? What's the common way to deal with such a situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to pin certs of third-party libs because they don't use your instance of the `OkHttpClient` with configured `CertificatePinner`.